# Getting the error "duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzble.class" when trying to add a package

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, build.gradle

I'm trying to add the `react-native-firestack` package to my app. But it keeps giving the following error :

```
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandDebug
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:generateBundledResourcesHashDebug
4f53cda18c2baa0c0354bb5f9a3ecbe5ed12ab4d8e11ba873c2f11161202b945
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzble.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.498 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment.
Go to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
and check the Android tab for setup instructions.
```

I tried to add some packages to `exclude group` in several packages. But none worked. Here's the `./gradlew clean :app:dependencies` result: https://gist.github.com/THPubs/8fe8b4b9c80e3c6cd49541d66887c742

Tried to follow other similar stack overflow question but looks like this package has a lot of dependencies. I was unable to find the conflict.

My `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(":react-native-firestack"))
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-uuid-generator')
    compile project(':react-native-udp')
    compile project(':react-native-tcp')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you use the same version in all your google play services libs:
For example :

```
     compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$project.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$project.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$project.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion"

    project.ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = '10.2.0'
}
```

Comment: This is what I had in my build.gradle file: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'`. I chanted it to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'`. I still get the same error that I had before that change: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class`.

Comment: indexing switched to firebase but the google play services versions still need to match: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10+' // GAID matching
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.+' // App indexing

Answer (score 4):

I got this error today when my dependencies were the following:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

But it went away when I changed the last dependency to the following:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
```

So make sure you use dependencies with same versions. That is the support libraries should have same version, and same goes for Firebase and Google Play dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle and run `gradle findDuplicates`

```
task findDuplicates {
    doLast {
        def findMe = 'com/google/android/gms/internal/zzble.class'
        configurations.compile.asFileTree.matching {
            include '**/*.jar'
        }.files.each { File jarFile ->
            zipTree(jarFile).visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
                if (fvd.path == findMe) {
                    println "Found $findMe in $jarFile.name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives error `Error:(202, 1) Execution failed for task ':app:findDuplicates'.
> Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container.`

Comment: Change the code from `configurations.runtime.xxx` to `configurations.compile.xxx` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` somewhere in your build.gradle file, probably on top.

**This line has to be after dependencies block** - this allows the plugin to determine what version of Play services you are using.

You can refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk for more information.

In your case it should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(":react-native-firestack"))
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-uuid-generator')
    compile project(':react-native-udp')
    compile project(':react-native-tcp')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
}

// after dependencies block
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best fix, but I can get past the problem by going into /node_modules/react-native-firestack/android/build.gradle and replacing all of the 10.0.1 with 10.2.0, and then making sure I use 10.2.0 everywhere in my own android/build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following in your build.gradle

```
    android {
            configurations {
            all*.exclude module: 'play-services-awareness'
            }
    }
```