# Android studio APK buil error transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android-studio, apk

I'm trying to build APK, but there is an error when I try to make it.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class

Following is my build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jordan.personicle"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile files('libs/ajt-2.9.jar', 'libs/javaml-0.1.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'

    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
        repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I think there is no duplication for gcm. What is the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: The problem is compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'. How should I solve this? which dependency can be duplicated with above?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same version in all your google play services libs:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42610163/1370087

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to synchronize the version, but still same error. compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. It still shows same error, though.