# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

The app compiles correctly in a device with Android 6.0, but not in a phone with Android 4.4.2. When I try to compile the project from Android Studio 2.2.3, using the device with Android 4.4.2, I receive this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class
```

In my `build.gradle` file, I am using this:

```
dependencies {
    ......
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    ......
}
```

I already tried `Build/Clean Project` as suggested by SergioLucas at [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug), and I also tried using the same version in all of the Google Play Services libs, as suggested by Benjamin at [Android studio APK buil error transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328593/android-studio-apk-buil-error-transformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug). In my case, using 9.8.0 for both `com.google.android.gms:play-services` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` did not fix the error. Any ideas? Thank you.

EDIT:

The app compiles correctly and zero problems on devices with Android 5.1.1, 5.0.1, and 6.0. I am experiencing this error only on my testing device with Android 4.4.2. See image error:

[image]

It intrigues me the fact that the error is only happening in Android 4.x, and everything compiles and works properly on devices with Android 5.x and 6.x. Maybe I need a specific library to make things compatible with older versions of Android, in this case Android 4.x? I will appreciate if you could provide any hints to fix this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the code that sampyng shared at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/3. This is what I had in my `app/build.gradle` file (version that was generating the error):

```
dependencies {
    .........
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    .........
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
}
```

The solution was replacing `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'` with

```
compile ("com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0") {
    exclude module: "play-services-gcm"
}
```

The final version of the code that fixed the error was:

```
dependencies {
    .........
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    .........
    compile ("com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0") {
        exclude module: "play-services-gcm"
    }
}
```

I also found at https://medium.com/wiselteach/firebase-jobdispatcher-androidmonk-3e6d729ed9ce a related article that may be helpful to explain the use of the Firebase JobDispatcher, but the official documentation is at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android.

I tested on devices with Android 4.4.2, 5.0.1, 5.1.1 and 6.0. The app compiles correctly for me now.