# Duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class

Tags: android, exception, callback, build.gradle, zipexception

I get this error when I try to generate a signed apk. Attachment code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:fabprogresscircle:1.01@aar'
    compile 'julianfalcionelli:MagicForm:1.4'
    compile 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:fillableloaders:1.03@aar'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.viewrevealanimator:view-reveal-animator:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile(name: 'datepickertimeline', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.savvi.datepicker:rangepicker:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.robertlevonyan.view:CustomFloatingActionButton:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:AutoFitTextView:4'
    compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.otaliastudios:autocomplete:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
    compile 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    compile 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
    /*compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.2.2'*/

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class

Comment: use `11.4.2` version.`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'`

Comment: I tried versions 11.4.2 and 11.8.0 and it's still the same

Comment: Try with `11.6.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the error "duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzble.class" when trying to add a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580096/getting-the-error-duplicate-entry-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzble-class)

Comment: I tried version 11.6.0 and nothing ... I will try your solution @EdsonMenegatti

Comment: It does not work

Comment: nobody knows what is going on?